# Mariadb python: Commands out of syncs

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, password-manager

so I was trying to create a password manager for myself, using python and mariadb. After creating a table named pw, which contains Name, Account and Passwords 3 columns, I tried to create a function(Search_Passwords(app_name)) which I can use to enter a keyword to search in the database, and it will give me the right passwords. However, I ran into this error message:
[Commands out of syncs error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdAw6.png)

I'm new to python and mariadb(using it cause for some reason MySQL doesn't work..), tried to look up for some answers but still can't figure it out. Can anyone help please? Below are other codes I think might be related.

[This is what mariadb's table looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP3kR.png)

[Search_Passwords()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luHGc.png)

[class UseDataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDxdT.png)

[This is what I found online as a reference version where Search_Passwords() involved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsY33.png)

Sorry if my codes are not perfect... :(

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which includes properly providing your code (copy and paste and format the code here as opposed to providing screenshots).

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB Connector/Python by default use unbuffered result sets, which means before executing another cursor all pending result sets need to be fetched or the cursor needs to be closed.

For example the following script

```
import mariadb

conn= mariadb.connect()
cursor1= conn.cursor()
cursor1.execute("select 1 from dual")
cursor2= conn.cursor()
cursor2.execute("select 2 from dual")
```

will throw an exception `Mariadb.InterfaceError: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`.

To avoid this, you need to create a buffered cursor:

```
cursor1= conn.cursor(buffered=True)
```

Comment: As per the new version (>=1.1.0) a [cursor is buffered by default](https://mariadb-corporation.github.io/mariadb-connector-python/connection.html).